# Terminal plugin for IntelliJ and PhpStorm doesn't work

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, fedora-25, phpstorm-2016.3

When I open the Terminal plugin in JetBrains IntelliJ or PhpStorm nothing seems to happen. Yes, I have, as is required in such circumstances, deployed ever increasing amounts of kinetic energy to my keyboard's return key - but nada:

[image]

The plugin is definitely installed:

[image]

My settings appear to be fine:

[image]

I've checked my `~/.PhpStorm2016/system/log/idea.log` file and nothing jumps out suggesting that the Terminal plugin is malfunctioning (it's the same with IntelliJ's log file).

Have I missed something?

I'm running:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.5 Build #IU-163.13906.18, built on March 6, 2017
>   JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by
>   JetBrains s.r.o
>
> PhpStorm 2016.3.3 Build #PS-163.13906.21, built on March 8, 2017 JRE:
>   1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>
> Fedora 25 x64 on actual hardware (HP Compaq Elite 8200, 8GB RAM,
>   NVidia Quadro FX1700 with dual LCD panels).

Comment: I can only suggest to [file a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with the [logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) attached.

Comment: @CrazyCoder if you're not able to suggest a solution then I guess I'm gonna have to :)